# Howto > 100% Width > Blueprint/960 2-column layout

Tags: css, compass-sass, blueprint-css, 960.gs

I'm new to Blueprint and 960 in Compass.

I've gotten a basic [2 column example](http://compass-style.org/examples/blueprint/grid/two_cols/) working with Blueprint. But I want to expand the width so the left & right panels take the entire screen (a la gmail). So the left column would be a fixed width, and the right column would expand as the window exapnds.

Using Compass (with Blueprint or 960), what's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got something working on this. I just use blueprint's basic .container class, with a margin of 0. All containers within that are stretching to the entire width of the screen.

To make the left pane a fixed width (not changing as window resizes), I mixed in a blueprint column of +column(2). I left the right pane alone, and gave it a margin that puts it beside the left pane. Presto, on window resizing, the left pane stays stationary and the right pane adjusts width.

HTH